# MySQL 5.7 is not compatible with cPanel; how you are using

Tags: cpanel, mysql-5.7

I was going to work on a new web project and found that mysql 5.7+, the latest entry, is not yet supported by cPanel.

Can you guys please share your experience, which work around you have found to this ?

Best.

Answer (score 0):

You can install MySQL 5.7 (percona) on a cPanel/WHM server by following these instructions:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/01/11/how-to-replace-mysql-with-percona-server-on-a-cpanel-or-whm-vps-or-dedicated-server/

But keep in mind, if you use MySQL 5.7 on a cPanel/WHM server it will break some of the mysql functionalities as in you won't be able to create mysql users using the cPanel/WHM web interface. So you'll have to create the respective mysql users manually

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is no longer the case. cPanel has recently mentioned it will now support MySQL 5.7 starting with cPanel & WHM version 70.

It maybe worth looking at again if you haven't found a solution yet.

Reference: https://blog.cpanel.com/being-a-good-open-source-community-member-why-we-hesitated-on-mysql-5-7/

Cheers!